# Why is my jar so big?

Tags: java, maven

I've got a relatively simple jar-with-dependencies being built with Maven that is way larger than it seems like it should be. It's around 20MB, and in order to figure out what's taking up so much space, I've done the following:

First, I ran `mvn dependency:tree`. Then I checked in my .m2 cache for the size of each of the jars in the dependency tree. If I add up all of those sizes, it comes to about 8MB. How can I figure out where the other 12MB are coming from?

One thing I noticed in looking through my .m2 was that for many of the dependencies, they'll have something like this:

```
total 5224
-rw-r--r--  1 user   289B Jul 25  2016 _remote.repositories
-rw-r--r--  1 user   1.7M Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-javadoc.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 user   407B Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 user   40B Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-javadoc.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 user   427K Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-sources.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 user   407B Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-sources.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 user   40B Jul 25  2016 commons-compress-1.12-sources.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 user   432K Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 user   407B Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 user   40B Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 user   13K Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.pom
-rw-r--r--  1 user   407B Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.pom.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 user   40B Jul 22  2016 commons-compress-1.12.pom.sha1
```

What are the -sources and -javadoc jars? Are those included in my uber jar? Because if every one of my dependencies uses the -javadoc jar instead of the standard one, that gets me a lot closer to 20MB.

Comment: If you use jar-with-dependencies means also including all transitive dependencies...bear that in mind...

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but `mvn dependency:tree` should still show me those dependencies. I'm trying to figure out where all of these other dependencies are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
jar tvvf <your_simple-jar-with-dependencies.jar>
```

Or, open it with any zip compatible archiver and examine the contents to determine what is being included. Alternatively, run maven with `-X` for more extensive runtime information.

Comment: Okay, I did that and see some things that shouldn't be included. How can I see where those are coming from if they aren't in my dependency tree though? Also, if I sum up the size of every class file listed, it sums to about 50M? Where's the extra coming from?